# Verdier duality on excellent schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology, derived-categories

Let  $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a regular morphism between  $k$-schemes which are noetherian and excellent with a funcion of dimension.

In the book by Illusie-Laszlo-Orgogozo, there is a theorem (4.4.1 in the chapter about duality) which says that if $K$ is a dualizing complex, then $f^{!}K$ also is.
As the morphism is regular, can we relate $f^{!}$ and $f^{*}$?

For example is it also true that $f^{*}K[-2\dim X]=f^{!}K[-2 dim Y]$?